# How to get proper slider in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 <?php 



                $slider_args=array(
                    'tag'=>array('featured','sticky'),
                    'post_per_page'=>5
                    );

                $slider=new WP_Query($slider_args);


                echo "<prev>";
                var_dump($slider->have_posts());
                echo "</prev>";
                if ( $slider->have_posts() ) {


                    while ( $slider->have_posts() ) {
                         $slider->the_post();
                    $thumb_id=get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($thmb_id,'full',true)
                    ?>
                    <li>

                        <a href="#slide1"><img src="<?php echo $thumb_url[0] ?>" alt="Welcome to Slippry!"></a>
                    </li>
                <?php
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                }
                ?>
```

Please someone tell me what the issue is.

I have this code in home.php but it is not running in the WordPress theme. When I run var_dump on `$slider->have_posts()` it's returning false.

Comment: are you sure you have posts associated with these tags ? And featured and sticky are tags not categories ?

Comment: yes,i try all thing do ...but it showing me same error

Answer (score 0):

The 'tag' in your query args is used for a category slugs and it accepts string as param not an array, so try

```
'tag' => 'featured, sticky',
```

Comment: i try this,it will give me same issue...@Angel Deykov